# From absolute to fixed element on flexbox layout

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

How would you make an element go from `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed;` when parent is `flexbox` ?

Let me explain further: I have a very basic layout 100% `flexbox` based. The layout is just a left sidebar and a content area. In the content area lives a header which starts at `400px` from the top and is absolutely positioned (in order to cover a hero section), the desired UX is to make this header sticky after it touches the top of the screen.

[Here is a pen for illustration.](https://codepen.io/jrodrigues/pen/xdPyvZ)

Now, I have the mechanism to programatically switch the header from `absolute` to `fixed` at a given scroll position, this is not a problem.

The problem is, when `fixed`: 
  1. the header covers the scrollbar to the right (real issue)
  2. left side of the header has to be known in order to set the `left:` property (minor issue: I can live with it as my sidebar has a fixed width I can copy from).

I heard about a `position:sticky` which does the trick, but it seems not that reliable as [not really well supported so far](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

Of course I cannot know size of the scrollbars as it depends on each navigators... otherwise I would just do `right:17px;` or something like that. ;)

**EDIT**

The culprit of the "bug" forcing the header to overlap the scrollbar is the `overflow:auto` set on `#content`.
However, as the layout is `flexbox` based, I don't see how to avoid use of this approach as the sidebar is sticky by definition using basic `flexbox`. So an underlying question would be: How to stick an element within flexbox, USING FLEXBOX ? The `position:fixed` is clearly not compatible as it breaks the flow... Also, the obvious step would be to avoid `flexbox` and redesign the whole layout using classical positioning, but this is out of the purpose: the layout has to be compatible with react-native which ignores classic CSS positioning (uses flexbox only)... [See here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html). (of course, react-native has another way to handle scrolling, hence the problem in web environments).

In order to proceed with my design, I had to make a decision and I went using `position:absolute` only, but adjusting my `top` property programatically (using react but could be implemented with Jquery or whatever technology able to know the current scroll position).

In pseudo-code, it would like :

```
//when scroll reaches 400px    
if getScrollTopPostion() > 400 

//recalculate top position of given element to equal current Scroll position. 
//This gives the effect that the element is sticky. In reality it is just live recalculated... 
//Quid of performances?? no idea
then setTop( getScrollTopPostion() ) 

//otherwise, let the element absolutely positioned at 400
else 400
```

Obviously, this does NOT answer the initial question.

The "official" answer would be to use `position:sticky`, but until it gets really spread across say 95% of browsers (particularly mobile ones...), I would say the proper answer is still to be found.

Comment: The problem with header covering the scroll is a simple fix, using a script that calc's the scrollbar width: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/tb4tck0x/2/

Answer (score 0):

For fixing the 1st issue, try this:
    #main #content #header {
     position: fixed;
     ...
    }
Remove the `overflow: auto;` property from `#content`. And also add `align-items:stretch` to `#sideBar`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer ! Unfortunately that won't work. Have a look at forked pen with your suggestion: [Your solution](https://codepen.io/jrodrigues/pen/EmoVQg)

Comment: Added some style changes, can you check this: [solution](https://codepen.io/jrodrigues/pen/EmoVQg).

Comment: Please ignore previous comment, try this: [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/kagx16zo/).

Comment: It works. Thanks for your patience. Actually the solution is a bit tricky as it involves knowing the size of the sidebar but hey, it's way way better than my poor remedy to programatically calculate the top position based on scroll :p  Just submit a proper answer I'll validate and upvote it.